# get a missing value for a column in one dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe 'persons' as below

```
name    age serial_no   mail
John    25  100483      john@abc.com
Sam     49  448900      sam@abc.com
Will    63              will@abc.com
Robert  20  299011  
Hill    78              hill@abc.com
```

I have another dataframe 'people' as below

```
name    s_no        e_mail
John    100483      john@abc.com
Sam     448900      sam@abc.com
Will    229809      will@abc.com                
Robert  299011  
Hill    567233      hill@abc.com
```

I need to add missing `serial_no` and `mail` in `persons` dataframe by joining it with `people` dataframe.
If `serial_no` is missing in `persons` dataframe, I need to join persons with `people` on `mail` column to get the `serial_no`.
If `mail` is missing in `persons` dataframe, I need to join `persons` with `people` on `serial_no` column to get the `mail`.
If there is no matching value found, `"NA"` should be loaded to it.

My final df should be like

```
name    age serial_no   mail
John    25  100483      john@abc.com
Sam     49  448900      sam@abc.com
Will    63  229809      will@abc.com            
Robert  20  299011      NA
Hill    78  567233      hill@abc.com
```

This is my code snippet

```
final_df = persons.join(people, (persons[serial_no] == people[s_no]) \
                    & (persons['serial_no'].isNull() | (persons['serial_no'] == people['s_no'])), how='left', \
                    persons['serial_no'], people['serial_no'], persons['mail'].alias('persons_mail'), \
                    people['e_mail'].alias('people_mail'], \
                    when(people['serial_no.people'].isNull(), "NA").otherwise(people['serial_no.people']).alias('serial_no_people'])))
```

Im blocked here and my code is not working. Can you pls suggest how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persons can be left joined with `people` two times, enriching one field for each join. On Scala (guess, can be converted to Python easily):

```
val persons = Seq(
  ("John", 25, Some(100483), "john@abc.com"),
  ("Sam", 49, Some(448900), "sam@abc.com"),
  ("Will", 63, None, "will@abc.com"),
  ("Robert", 20, Some(299011), null),
  ("Hill", 78, None, "hill@abc.com")
).toDF(
  "name", "age", "serial_no", "mail"
)
val people = Seq(
  ("John", 100483, "john@abc.com"),
  ("Sam", 448900, "sam@abc.com"),
  ("Will", 229809, "will@abc.com"),
  ("Robert", 299011, null),
  ("Hill", 567233, "hill@abc.com")
).toDF(
  "name", "s_no", "e_mail"
)
// Action
val serialsEnriched = persons
  .join(people, $"mail" === $"e_mail", "left")
  .select(
    persons.col("name"),
    $"age",
    coalesce($"serial_no", $"s_no", lit("NA")).alias("serial_no"),
    $"mail"
  )
val mailEnriched = serialsEnriched
  .join(people, $"serial_no" === $"s_no", "left")
  .select(
    persons.col("name"),
    $"age",
    $"serial_no",
    coalesce($"mail", $"e_mail", lit("NA")).alias("mail"),
  )
```

Output for `mailEnriched`:

```
+------+---+---------+------------+
|name  |age|serial_no|mail        |
+------+---+---------+------------+
|John  |25 |100483   |john@abc.com|
|Sam   |49 |448900   |sam@abc.com |
|Will  |63 |229809   |will@abc.com|
|Robert|20 |299011   |NA          |
|Hill  |78 |567233   |hill@abc.com|
+------+---+---------+------------+
```

Note: If duplicate `e_mail` or `s_no` is possible in `people`, some additional actions will be required for remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you overcomplicated the query, after joining you can use the [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) function to get the not null values from serial_no and s_no:

```
final_df = persons.join(people.select("s_no", "e_mail"), persons.mail == people.e_mail, "left")\
    .withColumn("serial_no", coalesce("serial_no", "s_no")).drop("s_no", "e_mail")
```